# Run hadoop job in oozie using jar file

Tags: hadoop, workflow, hadoop-yarn, sqoop, oozie

I have a jar file which is having sqoop job to read and write the data into mysql.

I want run the jar using oozie workflow and below is the command run the jar.

```
yarn jar aa-datalake.jar root root Orders avro aa-dl-rawzone
```

For this which action may I need to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably not the best idea to create an extra java wrapper upon your Sqoop job. You can use Sqoop directly from Oozie by using [Sqoop action](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.0.0/DG_SqoopActionExtension.html). You can set there same parameters you are using from your java app. If you still want to use your wrapper you can use [Java action](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.2.0-incubating/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a3.2.7_Java_Action) for this. But personally I consider this to be a piece of overhead for the task you've described.